# filter shakemaps by earthquake name (or id)

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

My goal is to be able to toggle shake intensities on / or off (display or hide) *individually* via either an `ID` or `name`... I see options of id and object id available in the data field options in the rest [doc](https://livefeeds.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/LiveFeeds/USGS_Seismic_Data/MapServer/).. however, I am unsure how to implement... In my below codepen, you can see I am doing a rest call and returning all the shake map data at once... I am trying to return them one at a time per earthquake name or ID... so, I can filter them later "on" or "off"...

[CodePen..](https://codepen.io/polpo26/pen/dyGGWzb?editors=1000)

Full Code:

---

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>ArcGIS JavaScript Tutorials: Add layers to a map</title>
  <style>
    html, body, #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
      "esri/widgets/Legend"
    ], function(Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, Legend) {
        var map = new Map({
            basemap: "gray"
        });

        var view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",  
            map: map,
            center: [-122, 37],
            zoom: 5            
        });

        view.ui.add(
            new Legend({
                view: view
          }),
            "bottom-left"
        );

    // Define a popup for USGS_Seismic_Data_v1
      var popupUSGS = {
        title: "Shake Intensity",
        content: [
          {
            type: "fields",
            fieldInfos: [
            {
                fieldName: "grid_value",
                label: "Grid Value"
              },
              {
                fieldName: "mag",
                label: "Magnitude"
              },
              {
                fieldName: "eventTime",
                label: "Event Time",
                format: {
                  dateFormat: "short-date-short-time"
                }
              },
              {
                fieldName: "updated",
                label: "Updated",
                format: {
                  dateFormat: "short-date-short-time"
                }
              },
              {
                fieldName: "url",
                label: "Url"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    // USGS_Seismic_Data_v1 feature layer (polygons)
      var SeismicData = new FeatureLayer({
        title: "MMI - Shake Intensity",
        url:  "https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/arcgis/rest/services/USGS_Seismic_Data_v1/FeatureServer/1/",
           outFields: ["mag","eventTime","url"],
          popupTemplate: popupUSGS
      });
      map.add(SeismicData);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the Esri tutorial, [Setting a definition expression](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#definitionExpression)

You can have a look at the code below:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    html, body, #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
      "esri/widgets/Legend"
    ], function(Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, Legend) {
        var map = new Map({
            basemap: "gray"
        });
        
        var view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",  
            map: map,
            center: [-122, 37],
            zoom: 5            
        });
        
        view.ui.add(
            new Legend({
                view: view
          }),
            "bottom-left"
        );
        
    // Define a popup for Shake Intensity
      var popupUSGS = {
        title: "Shake Intensity",
        content: [
          {
            type: "fields",
            fieldInfos: [
            {
                fieldName: "grid_value",
                label: "Grid Value"
              },
              {
                fieldName: "mag",
                label: "Magnitude"
              },
              {
                fieldName: "eventTime",
                label: "Event Time",
                format: {
                  dateFormat: "short-date-short-time"
                }
              },
              {
                fieldName: "updated",
                label: "Updated",
                format: {
                  dateFormat: "short-date-short-time"
                }
              },
              {
                fieldName: "url",
                label: "Url"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    // USGS_Seismic_Data_v1 feature layer (polygons)
      const SeismicData = new FeatureLayer({
        title: "MMI - Shake Intensity",
        url:  "https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/arcgis/rest/services/USGS_Seismic_Data_v1/FeatureServer/1/",
           outFields: ["mag","eventTime","url"],
          popupTemplate: popupUSGS
      });
      
      // Filter - intensities less than 2.0 
       SeismicData.definitionExpression = "grid_value > 2",
      map.add(SeismicData);
    });
    
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```